# Using Android Volley to Post and Obtain Json Data

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to post data using Android Volley and receive Json Response. I have the code below which I can't seem to see where the error is as all code I have found online is similar to this. I have attached screenshot of the message android is giving.

```
public String rBody = null;//Is Initialized also tried (String)null

  public void loadSharedPreferencesData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("userinfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String loggedStatus = sharedPre.getString("isLogged", "0");
    final String loggedUserId = sharedPre.getString("userId", "0");

    String loginUrl         = "http://dataUrl[![enter image description here][1]][1]/startvapp-ci/appdata/getsession/";

    JsonObjectRequest  jsonObjectRequest  = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrl, rBody ,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
                    //returnResponse = response.toString();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), returnResponse , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println(response);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in Response" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Save this to some global variable
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in Response" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_SESS_USERID,loggedUserId);
            params.put(KEY_SESS_STATUS,loggedStatus);
            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

[image: Android Studio Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message is stating that the `jsonRequest` argument is of the wrong type. It expects a `JSONObject`, but you are providing a `String` (the `rBody` variable).

If the `rBody` string is a valid JSON string, then you can simply pass that string to the `JSONObject` constructor. Then pass this `JSONObject` to the `JsonObjectRequest` constructor instead of `rBody`.

```
JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject(rBody);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, loginUrl, jsonRequest,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            // Response Listener code here
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            // Error Listener code here
        });
```

Comment: I have done this and the error is gone. However now i get error in response. What could be the cause. Also do i need rBody or i can just have JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();

Comment: I have managed to make this work using your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @jmsiox You would've needed to post the error in order for me to help with that. And if you want to actually *post* data; then yes, you would need to have a body. If you aren't posting data then you can just pass `null` as the third parameter instead of creating an empty `JSONObject()`.